# Кривое расширение экрана при запуске игры созданной в юнити

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуй, я новичок в юнити и вообще без понятия почему так выходит. Суть в том что когда я пишу игру она у меня выглядит примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я её запускаю уже в скомпилированном виде на своем пк получается что-то такое... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И то и то в окне "Game"? Или может быть одно в окне "Scene", а при нажатии показывается "Game"?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 1-й скрин это в юнити "Game" а 2-й скрин это уже скомпилированый вариант (не юнити) а exe файл